# REACT-NATIVE SyntaxError unterminated JSX contents (57:41)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Help, Im trying code an app an I can't seem to get past this error.

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 30,
    marginTop: 65,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC'
  },
  title: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  searchInput: {
    height: 50,
    padding: 4,
    marginRight: 5,
    fontSize: 23,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 8,
    color: 'white'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#111',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 45,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});

class Main extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text> Testing the Router </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
};

module.exports = Main;
```

I believe the problem lies in this block

```
class Main extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text> Testing the Router </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
};
```

There error message is: SyntaxError /Users/tevinrivera/Rondeh/App/Components/Main.js: Unterminated JSX contents(57:41)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your imports are wrong. You need to import React from 'react' and other things like View, Stylesheet etc from 'react-native'.

Something like will work:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. Try changing this code

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} = React;
```

to this

```
const React = require('React');
const ReactNative = require('react-native');
const{
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text
} = ReactNative;
```

Comment: So @TevinRivera I copied your code into one of my project and all I had to do was changing the imports and it worked. Check my new updated answer Hope it helps.